# Python 3.5 - Tkinter Using variables for filenames + paths

Tags: python, python-3.x, combobox, tkinter

I have a combo box which always sets two variables
1) is a filename (.csv)
2) is a file path location

Depending on what is selected in the combo box, a particular .csv file is allocated to variable `csvfilename` and a path is allocated to `path`

I'm trying to feed these variables into the below code to load certain files from a fixed file location.

`with open(csvfilename) as csvfile:`

and

```
self.DwgOutputBox.tag_bind("dwg", "<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event, filename=path + '/' + linkname: subprocess.run(filename, shell=True))
```

however I'm getting a
 `"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'StringVar' and 'str'"` message when testing using the PATH variable

and a

`with open(csvfilename) as csvfile: TypeError: invalid file: tkinter.StringVar object at 0x024F4F50` when trying to use the csv variable.

When I test the code by setting the path and csv filename myself it works correctly, so it appears to be an issue with either not being able to use variables for file names or my syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`path` is a `StringVar` object, and you are trying to add `/` to it.

Instead of trying to define a keyword argument, pass in the `StringVar` objects (`path` and `linkname`) and get their values *in the `lambda`*:

```
self.DwgOutputBox.tag_bind(
    "dwg", "<ButtonRelease-1>",
    lambda event, path=path, linkname=linkname: subprocess.run(
        os.path.join(path.get(), linkname.get()), shell=True))
```

The `path.get()` call retrieves the current value of the `StringVar` object. I used `os.path.join()` instead of manual concatenation so that your code also works on an OS where the path separator is not `/`.

You'll have to do something similar for the `with open(...)` call; retrieve the string values contained *in* the `StringVar` objects.

Comment: thank you I shall attacking it from this angle, appreciate you taking the time to reply :)

Answer (score 1):

A tkinter Stringvar is not a python string.  To return the value of a Stringvar you use `variable.get()`

Since `path` is not a string you cant add a string to it, put `path.get() + ...` . What happens if tye path entered doesn't exist? Does the progrsm crash?